# Difference between :input and input in Jquery

Tags: jquery

On some tutorials, I've seen these selectors:

```
$(':input');
```

or

```
$('input');
```

Note the ':'.

Are there any differences?

Comment: `:input`: _Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements._ `input` selects input element.

Comment: You can search the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/?s=input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$('input')` = with only the element name, selects only HTML  elements.

`$(':input')` = with the colon, selects/filter all form input type elements, including **input**, **select**, **textarea**, and **button** elements.

Refer to the jQuery selector information:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: You might want to link to the docs, and repeat, as the docs say, that: `:input` is a jQuery extension, so it should be used to *filter* elements, rather than used as a selector (to take advantage of `querySelectorAll()`).

Answer (score 3):

`$('input')` selects all `input` elements, such as <**input** type="radio", <**input** type="text", <**input** type="checkbox", etc. It would not select any other form elements (such as `<select...` or `<button...` elements, for example).

From the [jQuery input-selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)* we see

> The `:input` selector basically selects all form controls.

So `$(':input')` would get <**input** ... as well as <**textarea** ..., <**select** ..., <**button** ..., etc.

*-The same page also notes

> Because :input is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :input cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using :input to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":input").